# map subdomain to another subdomain via cname

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record

**Question:**  I need to get DNS configured to point a subdomain from one domain (which I will generally not be controlling) to another subdomain on a different domain name. Testing this process using a simple CNAME entry keeps pointing to the primary domain and not the subdomain where it should be going.

**This is the scenario;** (newdomain.com is in my control)

- **cdn.xyz.com** should display content from this subdomain ***subdomain*.newdomain.com**
- It is instead displaying content from **newdomain.com** (not the ***subdomain*** sub domain)
- **cdn.xyz.com/page.htm** displays content from **newdomain.com/page.htm** although what I need is it to display content from **subdomain.newdomain.com/page.htm**

**Other Background:**

- setup is between two different servers with different IP ranges although DNS cluster is on between all servers
- the **newdomain.com** is set up with its own unique IP (which is on the A records for the subdomains, the subdomains work as expected/normal)
- the DNS entry is correct (cdn CNAME subdomain.newdomain.com.) ie the end period is included
- a DNS lookup on the CNAME externally reports back as subdomain.newdomain.com. as the record

Does anyone know what DNS entries I am missing to get this working correctly ?

*Note: I do not want to just put a redirect between domains as I need the content of **subdomain.newdomain.com/content.html** to be visible via the URL of **cdn.xyz.com/content.html** also I can just use some redirects on newdomain.com to achieve what I am after but would prefer to just get the DNS correct.*

**EDIT**

Current DNS

> cdn **CNAME** subdomain.newdomain.com. || CNAME entry for domain1
>
> subdomain **A** XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX || A record entry for working subdomain pointing to unique IP
>
> What should happen is that cdn.domain1.com -> subdomain.newdomain.com

What is happening is cdn.domain1.com -> newdomain.com (ie. the root not the subdomain)

**EDIT 2**

Actually if its easier I am trying to emulate a simple cloud setup like Rackspace Containers (which I assume is similar to Buckets on AWS). *although it is not for cloud storage*

Where a container has a url reference of hd62321678d323.rackspace.com (in truth they are much longer) so I can use a CNAME record of:
cdn CNAME hd62321678d323.rackspace.com.

so that http://cdn.mydomain.com/myfile.jpg displays content from http://hd62321678d323.rackspace.com/myfile.jpg

Comment: Can you edit your question to list the current DNS configuration you have in place?  I'm really confused by your question as to what you have in place.  A simple `CNAME xyz.abc.com -> abc.xyz.com` would be perfect.

Comment: How is it all configured? Kan you show the zone-file or the equivalent? Or at least the SOA-, A- and CNAME records you have entered?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a DNS problem.

You have to tell the web server at address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX how to handle requests for `cdn.xyz.com`. See your web server's documentation for (name-based) virtual hosting.

If you are using Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html